# Singular part of the pole at $z=0$ of $f(z)= \pi^2 / \sin^2(\pi z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

In $z=0$, $f(z)$ has a pole of order 2, and I know that the singular part in this case is $\frac{1}{z^2}$, but I dont know how to obtain this result.

Any help.

Answer (score 5):

Consider
$$
g(z)=\frac{\pi^2z^2}{\sin^2(\pi z)}
$$
This has a removable singularity at $0$, and the limit is $1$. Thus the Taylor series at $0$ for the extended function $\hat{g}$ is
$$
1+a_2z^2+a_4z^4+\dotsb
$$
(the odd terms are missing because the function is even). Thus, for $z\ne0$,
$$
f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}+a_2+a_4z^2+\dotsb
$$

Comment: What about singular part at integers?Is it 1/(z-n)^2,where n is an integer?If so,how to prove this?Any hints

Comment: @BalasubramannyanS Studying the singular part at $n$ is the same as studying the singular part of $F(w)=f(w+n)$ at $0$ and then substituting in the Laurent series $z-n$ for $w$.. What can you notice? Yes, $F(w)=f(w)$.

Comment: All integers are periods of the given function.So behavior of function in the neighborhood of a integer is same as in the neighborhood of zero.So Lawrent's series about any integer n is got by replacing z by z-n in the Lawrent's series expansion of f about 0.Am I right?

Comment: @BalasubramannyanS Yes, that's correct.